# CVS checkout with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, cvs

I'm trying to define an ansible playbook to checkout several sources from CVS, just similarly to what I do with the git module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html). Unfortunately there's no cvs module as far as I can tell.
Is there any recommended way to go about it?

Comment: you can write own module :) But I'd use the shell/command

Comment: a pointer to an existing solution would be a great help

Comment: unfortunately I'm stuck with passing the 'cvs login' password to the ansible shell... any idea how that would work?

Comment: If you could use SSH for login this is a more or less example to get you started:
`- name: Remove cvs mirror host key
  shell: ssh-keygen -R {{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }}

- name: Add cvs mirror host key
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H {{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }} >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

- name: Get OpenBSD cvs src
  shell: cvs -qd anoncvs@{{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }}:/cvs checkout -P src
  args:
    chdir: /usr/cvs_current
creates: /usr/cvs_current/src`

Answer (score 0):

If you could use SSH for login this is more or less an example to get you started:

```
- name: Remove cvs mirror host key
  shell: ssh-keygen -R {{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }}

- name: Add cvs mirror host key
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H {{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }} >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

- name: Get OpenBSD cvs src
  shell: cvs -qd anoncvs@{{ openbsd_cvs_mirror }}:/cvs checkout -P src
  args:
    chdir: /usr/cvs_current
    creates: /usr/cvs_current/src
```

Comment: unfortunately we do not have anonymous access, therefore I need to find a way to pass the cvs login